# C3 Charts: Hiding Keys on Bar Graphs

Tags: javascript, charts, c3

I've looked through all of the documentation and can't find a way to hide the keys for a bar graph.

Basically, I'd like to remove the 'total' and color at the bottom. Has anyone found a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Can you include a link to your code and explain what you mean with keys ? From this picture it looks like you just want to omit rendering the legend at the bottom ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

legend: {
   hide: true
}